# Set VM option from maven config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, cmd

Is there any way to set an argument for the command line from the maven config? Maybe some plugin?

I need to run my service on spring boot with the following VM option:

```
-Dspring.config.additional-location=classpath:/config/business-config.yml
```

I have tried using `maven-surefire-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <argLine>
          -Dspring.config.additional-location=classpath:/config/business-config.yml
        </argLine>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and `spring-boot-maven-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <jvmArguments>
          -Dspring.config.additional-location=classpath:/config/business-config.yml
        </jvmArguments>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But that doesn't work for me. I test by running my maven project locally from **IDEA Intellij** as a Spring Boot application. If I set this option in IDEA configuration then it works properly.

Any ideas why?

Comment: what happens when you build the jar and run that? because that is what you should only care for

Comment: Nothing. Build is successful, but the VM option is not installed when I start the service through the IDEA. No any exceptions or errors. But if I set the VM option in Edit Configuration of IDEA then it's applied properly

Comment: "but the VM option is not installed when I start the service through the IDEA" - I said build the executable jar. Its not like you will be running in prod from your IDE. you know what the spring executable jar is, right?

Answer (score 0):

Maven is a build tool, not a runtime environment.

For the simplest see [The java Command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html):

> `java ... -Dproperty=value ...`
>
> Sets a system property value. The *property* variable is a string with no spaces that represents the name of the property. The *value* variable is a string that represents the value of the property. If *value* is a string with spaces, then enclose it in quotation marks (for example `-Dfoo="foo bar"`).

Otherwise the container your application is running in has to have a possibility to configure `java` command line parameters.

Comment: Maven can execute classes with the configured build path.   For some reason this has not been leveraged into a deployment tool.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yes it does it with test code by default (via the Surefire/Failsafe plugins) and there are also other plugins that do that: `exec-maven-plugin`, `jetty:start`, `hpi:run` etc. What do you exactly mean by "_has not been leveraged into a deployment tool_"? Where and how should this be integrated in Maven in an other way but by plugins?